# Discord Py error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: discord, discord.py

```py
async def on_message(message):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(f"https://dathost.net/api/0.1/game-servers/{config.dathost_gameserver}", 
                                    auth=aiohttp.BasicAuth(config.dathost_user, config.dathost_pass)) as r:
            if r.status == 200:
                game_servers = await r.json()

    for gameserver in game_servers:
        raw_ip = gameserver['raw_ip']
        server_status = gameserver['on']

    if server_status == False:
        serverstate = 'OFFLINE'
        if message.content.lower() == '!test':
            embed = discord.Embed(description=raw_ip)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

The error is `TypeError: string indices must be integers.`

Ive been told the error is obvious but as a beginner i am still unsure how to fix this error.

Comment: on which line does the error occur? type error means that something is not the correct type, whether it is `string` `integer` and others. string indices must be an `integer` which is a whole number

Comment: @TheSavageTeddy Sorry about that i forgot to mention that. it says the error is at raw_ip = gameserver['raw_ip']

Comment: then `gameserver` is not a dictionary, but instead either a `list` or a `string`

Comment: ```
{
  "id": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "user_data": "string",
  "game": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "players_online": 0,
  "status": [
    {
      "key": "string",
      "value": "string"
    }
  ],
  "booting": true,
  "server_error": "string",
  "ip": "string",
  "raw_ip": "string",
  "on": true,
  "ports": {
    "game": 0,
    "gotv": 0
  },
```

Comment: thats the output of the json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know the problem

The JSON data is from here

```py
game_servers = await r.json()
```

The variable is named `game_servers` with a `_`

Here

```py
    for gameserver in game_servers:
        raw_ip = gameserver['raw_ip']
        server_status = gameserver['on']
```

The variable `gameserver` without the `_` is equal to the first dictionary value (for example, say `game_servers` is  `{ "id": "string", "name": "string"}` then `gameserver` is going to be `"id", "name"`. See [this](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/#iterating-through-keys-directly))

So it should be

```py
        raw_ip = game_servers['raw_ip']
        server_status = game_servers['on']
```

WITH the `_` instead of

```py
        raw_ip = gameserver['raw_ip']
        server_status = gameserver['on']
```

The for loop is also unnecessary

Comment: Ok ill give it a go. So i should forget about using the for loop?

Comment: yes probably, not sure why it was used in the first place.

Comment: Thanks mate i feel kinda stupid for adding that for loop in. haha